Issues Fetching Email Stats (analytical data) with a Specific Category from SendGrid API (403 & 400 Errors)
I’m trying to fetch email stats and message records with a specific category from the SendGrid API, but I’m encountering two different errors depending on the account type I use.
What I’m Trying to Do:
I want to retrieve email activity data and stats for messages that belong to a specific category. Here’s the code I’m using to achieve this:
import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient

# Ensure your SendGrid API key is set correctly
api_key = os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
sg = SendGridAPIClient(api_key)

# Define query parameters to search for emails with the specific category
params = {
    'query': 'category="your_category"',  # Replace with your category name
    'limit': 50  # Limit the number of results
}

try:
    # Fetch email activity
    response = sg.client.messages.get(query_params=params)
    
    # Check response status
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Email Activity Details:", response.body)  # Successful response
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.body}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Exception occurred: {str(e)}")


The Issues:

When using a paid account: I get the following error:

Exception occurred: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden



When using a free account: I get this error:

Exception occurred: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request


What I’ve Tried:
I verified that the category name is correct.
I tried adjusting the query parameters, but the same issues persist.
What I Need:

403 Forbidden (Paid Account): Why is this happening when I’m using a paid account with what I believe are the correct permissions?
400 Bad Request (Free Account): Is this a limitation of the free tier, or am I doing something wrong with the request?

I’d appreciate any guidance on how to resolve these issues and correctly retrieve email stats and messages filtered by category.
